# How to calculate the percentage increasment in java

Tags: java

I want to calculate the increase of percentage of a variable from type int while using another variable from type int for the percentage (50 percent).
thanks in advance for anyone who is willing to help.

`

```
int a = 3;
int percentage = 3 / 2;

// here I get 3 instead of 4 which is the required answer.
a = a * percentage;
System.out.println(a);

// but here I get the required answer normally.
a = 3;
a = a * 3 / 2;
System.out.println(a);
```

`

Comment: Hint: `int` stands for [**int**eger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer).

Answer (score 2):

"Percentage" is just a weird of "this value that generally is between 0 and 1 should be rendered by multiplying by 100 and adding a % symbol afterwards". In other words, it's **purely a way to display a thing**. `50%` means `0.5`.

`int` cannot represent 0.5. `double` sort of can (double and float aren't perfectly accurate). In addition `/` is integer division if both the left and right side are ints. So, we need to do a few things:

```
int a = 3;
double b = 1.0 * 3 / 2; // without that 1.0 *, it wouldn't work
System.out.println(b); // prints "1.5"
double c = a * b;
System.out.println(c); // prints 4.5.
int d = ((int) (a * b) + 0.1);
System.out.println(d); // prints 4
```

Because doubles aren't entirely accurate, and `(int)` rounds down, adding a small delta (here, 0.1) is a good idea. Otherwise various values will surprise you and go wrong (say, your math ends up at 3.99999999, solely because `double` is not perfectly accurate, then casting that to int gets you a 3).